# Add keyboard shortcut for Search

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

## Overview

- I have a SwiftUI list with a search field
- I would like to add a keyboard shortcut for search field to be in focus

## Questions:

1. How can I add a keyboard shortcut for search field?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(0..<100) { index in
                Text("Cell \(index)")
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
        }
    }
}
```